# How do I win in Wayward?

Tags: wayward

I understand I am supposed to "find treasure", but don't know how to do it.

When I learned to play well enough to stay alive, I went exploring into the underground (and found nothing but empty chests). I'd tried using/"decoding" a map I'd found in a bottle, but that only told me I am nowhere near a treasure.

I've tried googling on Google, their web and Youtube but haven't found anything useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you decode a map It will display where the treasure is on your mini-map, but not clearly. There should be a green dot on the mini-map display that indicates where the treasure is. I hope this helps.

Comment: Ok, why not, accepting. 
Welcome to the site. Also get this upvote to get you at least up to 100 rep quickly. :)